# How to use centralized resources with Hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, architecture

People seem to be very keen to move existing applications to a Hadoop infrastructure and in many companies or organizations there seems to be a mantra: if you have lots of data, use Hadoop. 
I would like to understand how the dependency that existing solutions have on centralized (big) data impacts the decision if Hadoop is a good solution or not.

In many cases, your typical "big data"  application wants to process billions of things, e.g. documents, messages, files as efficiently and fast as possible. I see the advantage of distributing that work among many nodes in a map/reduce fashion. 
However, more often than not, in order to be able to process these things, the processing function (the mapper) has to lookup up stuff somewhere. For example, send queries to a SQL server, look something up in a graph database, find data in a huge key/value store. Also, each function needs possibly a huge amount of memory to store/cache all the data it needs to process its thing.

Is this something that is against the Hadoop way of doing things or are things commonly done that way? The bottom line then would be that in addition to spreading your processing work over a bunch of Hadoop nodes, you would need to find a way how to parallelize or upscale or your "central servers" (SQL, Graph database etc.) so they can answer all the requests coming from the parallel Hadoop nodes, wouldn't you?

What is the best way to move towards using Hadoop when the processing that is getting parallized depends on fast lookups in huge central data stores?

Answer (score 0):

That's why you have solutions like Cassandra. Naturally you can't just massively parallelize the computation, but keep the data store as a single entity. You'll need to parallelize related resources as well.

Comment: Thank you - but there is still something very basic I do not understand: the mapreduce model seems to be based on the assumption that the things that need to get processed can be split up between nodes and than map can process them -- each node the set of data that is locally available on that node. But when we need to look up data from a central store, each map process needs to get potential access to some data among billions of potential records. With this scenario you cannot split it up nicely. How can you move a large RDF store with billions of triples  to that architecture to do lookups?